# Absolutely positioned div not taking the full height while applying translate X or left on other elements

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have fallen into a weird CSS, I am working with TailwindCSS, and here is the sandbox link for someone to see what am i exactly facing [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/Biki-das/Test-App/draft/interesting-bogdan?workspace=%257B%2522activeFileId%2522%253Anull%252C%2522openFiles%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522gitSidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522COMMIT%2522%252C%2522spaces%2522%253A%257B%2522clc5taxeo00772a68c7l1nuzb%2522%253A%257B%2522key%2522%253A%2522clc5taxeo00772a68c7l1nuzb%2522%252C%2522name%2522%253A%2522Default%2522%252C%2522devtools%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522key%2522%253A%2522clc5teils000d2a68352v2uq1%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PROJECT_SETUP%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PREVIEW%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522clc5taztl00bi2a68q66n3m66%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522clc5taymx009q2a6837ur5jbi%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522currentSpace%2522%253A%2522clc5taxeo00772a68c7l1nuzb%2522%252C%2522spacesOrder%2522%253A%255B%2522clc5taxeo00772a68c7l1nuzb%2522%255D%257D), currently the mobile Nav which is an absolutely positioned div height seems to get affected whenever I try to put translate X or left positioning values on any other element. An explanation of where I went wrong would help me a lot because I have been struggling a lot with these.

Comment: Questions are supposed to include code, not links to third party websites. Please read [ask], [edit] to create a [mcve]